# Optimizing Microsoft Queries from Oracle DB in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, performance, odbc

I am using around 40 tables queried using microsoft query in excel. They establish different connections but connection string is same. The queries are all `select * from x`. `x` in this case is oracle db view. I benchmarked the execution time using visual basic script:
[Excel ODBC Data Connection Query time taken to refresh each query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42972568/excel-odbc-data-connection-query-time-taken-to-refresh-each-query)

On average, the connection shown by vba is 4 times slower than executing the views directly on database using datagrip. So, in total it takes 25s to refresh whole excel workbook which is totally unacceptable. To give an example of a particular view, if it takes 85ms on Datagrip, it takes around 350ms in excel (this is after using materialized views as detailed below).

Fast Data Load in excel is already selected. The queries do not rely on one another, so there is no same connection or query being called multiple times. There are no transformations to data, so query folding (whose details I did not read into) should not be an issue.

I further created materialized view. This did reduce latency in excel (e.g. 1.5s to 1.15 second or 600ms to 350ms for two sample views). However improvement in datagrip (4x) is far more than in excel (1.5x-2x) and this is not due to caching by datagrip (caching reduces 85ms further to around 30ms).

The total excel file with data is only around 1.5 mb.

**What further techniques can I use to improve refresh time in excel?**

I would like to reduce to this 4-5 seconds. As The largest query/view has 4000 rows. 2 more views have around 100-200 rows and others contain on average 10x20 tables. Some are even smaller.